# Visual Studio 2013: watch window break on changing value

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

in previous version of visual studio using watch window and while monitoring a variable it is possible to break the program if the value is changing.

[image]

Can anyone help me with Visual studio 2013 making a similar behaviour?
thanks

Comment: Data breakpoints were never supported in managed code, quite incompatible with the garbage collector and the lack of an interpreter.  Best way to get one back is to use a property, you can set a breakpoint on the setter.

Comment: Hello Hans, i'm a quite noob in this. Can you send me a sample?

Comment: There is no way I can help you stop being a noob by doing the work for you.  Just google "vb.net property example".